# Why is Abel's Identity (Apostol Theorem 4.2) valid for complex functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Apostol uses the Abel Identity developed early in his book as Theorem 4.2 (image below)

$$ \sum_{y<n\leq x}= A(x)f(x) - A(y)f(y) - \int_{y}^{x}A(t)f'(t) dt $$

to prove a result about complex Dirichlet series (11.6 Lemma 2, image below).

**Question** - Why is the Abel Identity valid in the complex domain?

---

**My thoughts**

The derivation he presents for Theorem 4.2 is only for functions in the real domain.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I paid for a copy of the book and believe the images fall under "fair use". If this is not the case, I will remove them.

Comment: If you look at the proof of the theorem 4.2, it does not use the fact that $f$ takes its values in $\mathbb{R}$, so it also works if $f$ takes complex values.